# Merge one object inside another object of json file

Tags: jq

As I am working first time in shell scripts and json parser i.e. jq library.

I wanted to merge details one of property of file1 and file2 inside another file3 along with rest of the property details.

Was able to merge properties of file1 and file2, but failing as complete details to render within file3.

Basically failing to assign stored value to particular key property in file3

j1.json

```
{
  "catalog": {
    "git_branch_name": "Release_Sprint1912",
    "git_commit_number": "7ff5358b6d919228ae6043f7bb64abd890c6dfe9",
    "git_repo_name": "catalog"
  },
  "swirl_components": {
    "git_branch_name": "Release_Sprint1912",
    "git_commit_number": "78ed0b1d0e25a261b89160a037530cf6c594892f",
    "git_repo_name": "swirl_components"
  },
  "demo_app": {
    "git_repo_name": "demo_app",
    "git_branch_name": "Release_Sprint1912",
    "git_commit_number": "1f227bb19343d19629b302c425adb8f21f4fab5a"
  }
}
```

j2.json

```
{
  "swirl_app": {
    "version": "readBuildInfo_311",
    "image_name": "/swirl_app:readBuildInfo_311",
    "date_time": "Mon Mar 25 05:55:45 UTC 2019",
    "git_latest_commit": "4b7bef6970f83e6e7fc04302c8b29d7cfd4a1885",
    "jenkins_build_url": "http://10.229.6.14/job/HC_Dev/job/Code-Build/job/swirl_app/311/",
    "artifactory_path": "ARTIFACTORY PATH"
  }
}
```

OutPut Expected:

```
{
  "catalog": {
    "git_branch_name": "Release_Sprint1912",
    "git_commit_number": "7ff5358b6d919228ae6043f7bb64abd890c6dfe9",
    "git_repo_name": "catalog"
  },
  "swirl_components": {
    "git_branch_name": "Release_Sprint1912",
    "git_commit_number": "78ed0b1d0e25a261b89160a037530cf6c594892f",
    "git_repo_name": "swirl_components"
  },
  "demo_app": {
    "git_repo_name": "demo_app",
    "git_branch_name": "Release_Sprint1912",
    "git_commit_number": "1f227bb19343d19629b302c425adb8f21f4fab5a"
  },
  "swirl_app": {
    "git_repo_name": "demo_app",
  "git_branch_name": "Release_Sprint1912",
  "git_commit_number": "1f227bb19343d19629b302c425adb8f21f4fab5a",
  "version": "readBuildInfo_311",
  "image_name": "/swirl_app:readBuildInfo_311",
  "date_time": "Mon Mar 25 05:55:45 UTC 2019",
  "git_latest_commit": "4b7bef6970f83e6e7fc04302c8b29d7cfd4a1885",
  "jenkins_build_url": "http://10.229.6.14/job/HC_Dev/job/Code-Build/job/swirl_app/311/",
  "artifactory_path": "ARTIFACTORY PATH"
  }
}
```

tried:

```
j1=$(echo jq "." j1.json) 
j2=$(echo jq "." j2.json)
demo=$(echo jq '.demo_app' j1.json)
jq -s 'add' $j1 $j2
jq ".swirl_app" j2.json >> swirl.json
jq '.demo_app' j1.json >> demo.json
jq -s 'add' demo.json swirl.json
total=$(echo jq -s 'add' demo.json swirl.json)
```

fails or trying to:

```
jq ".swirl_app={}" j3.json // makes empty object of "swirl_app": {}
jq ".swirl_app=$total" j3.json // this fails as expect result
jq ".swirl_app|=$total" j3.json // this too fails as expected result
```

My thoughts:
1) Should we make it array? and then assign value
2) Above variable assign works but incorrectly done?

Final:
Need help over this, to understand what is wrong from my side.

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Slurp the files in so you can combine them, then update the objects accordingly.

```
$ jq -s 'add | .swirl_app = .demo_app + .swirl_app' j{1,2}.json > j3.json
```

```
{
  "catalog": {
    "git_branch_name": "Release_Sprint1912",
    "git_commit_number": "7ff5358b6d919228ae6043f7bb64abd890c6dfe9",
    "git_repo_name": "catalog"
  },
  "swirl_components": {
    "git_branch_name": "Release_Sprint1912",
    "git_commit_number": "78ed0b1d0e25a261b89160a037530cf6c594892f",
    "git_repo_name": "swirl_components"
  },
  "demo_app": {
    "git_repo_name": "demo_app",
    "git_branch_name": "Release_Sprint1912",
    "git_commit_number": "1f227bb19343d19629b302c425adb8f21f4fab5a"
  },
  "swirl_app": {
    "git_repo_name": "demo_app",
    "git_branch_name": "Release_Sprint1912",
    "git_commit_number": "1f227bb19343d19629b302c425adb8f21f4fab5a",
    "version": "readBuildInfo_311",
    "image_name": "/swirl_app:readBuildInfo_311",
    "date_time": "Mon Mar 25 05:55:45 UTC 2019",
    "git_latest_commit": "4b7bef6970f83e6e7fc04302c8b29d7cfd4a1885",
    "jenkins_build_url": "http://10.229.6.14/job/HC_Dev/job/Code-Build/job/swirl_app/311/",
    "artifactory_path": "ARTIFACTORY PATH"
  }
}
```